# Does canvas.drawBitmap redraw the whole screen in android?

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I am using a `surfaceholder` and `canvas` in android to stream a video stream to the phone. My algorithm writes rectangles onto the bitmap, but only some rectangles change. I change the bitmap with setpixels. Then I call `onDraw(canvas)` and it does `canvas.drawBitmap(image, 0, 0, null)` which redraws the bitmap. But will it use extra resources redrawing areas that have not changed? Should I make a bitmap for each tile instead and only redraw the ones that change?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are worried about your performance. If your image represents the whole screen, it's definitely the canvas will draw a big bitmap. But you mentioned you use rectangle to changed the bitmap with setpixels. why don't you make these pixels a small bitmap? and draw the small bitmap by

```
canvas.drawBitmap(smallImage, x, y, paint)
```